# How do I book a one-way ticket from Paris (CDG) to Toronto (YYZ) from Paris?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, cdg, yyz

I'm Canadian and I want to know what my options are of booking a one-way ticket in Paris without a printer & how to actually get the physical ticket in hand. What are the most efficient & wallet-friendly options?

Edit: I must say I have never done the e-ticket process & my phone dies too quickly. I don't want to depend on my phone. What are the other options? How does the e-ticket process work at the CDG?

Comment: E ticket on the phone.

Comment: Relevant to the edited-in last paragraph: an "e-ticket" **doesn't** depend on the _passenger_ having a phone or other electronic device to store it on. A printout of the booking confirmation -- or for that matter, just a handwritten note with the booking and eticket numbers on it -- is all the check-in desk needs for matching the name on the booking to the name on your passport and issue a boarding pass. _Their_ computer system does all the electronic work.

Comment: Try Air Transat or Iceland Air for reasonably priced one-way flights between Paris and Toronto

Comment: Your options are, cash or plastic, and someone else's printer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm True, but you should be aware that some airports do not permit entry into the airport itself unless you have a printout of the eticket. If you dont, you need to pay an insane amount (for a printout) to the airline office to get one, and enter the airport using that

Comment: @Akash Thanks for the info! This is the sort of angle of info I was lookimg for... :-)

Comment: @verve ok.. so I guess I missed that the location names were mentioned in the question initially..  that was valid for some airports in India, and they charge the equivalent of USD 2-3 for printing. Insane for India, maybe not so for you :). Flying from US, I've been checked in with just my passport, they scanned it and the ticket details popped up on their screen. Didnt need the e ticket also

Answer (score 5):

Very few airlines issue paper tickets these days. You can walk up to the counter with wad of money and get one, but that's really not wallet friendly.

You can easily book online and get a confirmation number and an e-ticket number as your receipt. Doing this at least a week or two ahead of flying will increase the chances of getting a cheap ticket. On flying day you can check in online or at the airport. At the airport you can walk up to the kiosk put in your confirmation number and the kiosk will print your boarding pass. Since it's international travel you may have to go to the bag drop off to have your travel documents verified. If you don't like the kiosk you can go to check in counter and have a real person check you in and print your boarding pass. It just takes longer. Details depend somewhat on the airline.

Comment: I have *walked up to the counter* and got a ticket in the past.  They gave me an e-ticket.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on buying certain tickets if not a resident of France?  That's actually what I was initially wondering.. oh, the wonders of lack of sleep. Lol